# Exception class - what() function

Tags: c++, exception, error-handling

I'm currently working on my own exception class that inherits from `std::exception`, and I'm not sure if I should make my own `what()` or just call
`std::exception("message")` in my class constructor.
This is my current code:

```
FilterException::FilterException(const char* message, int num) noexcept :
    error_message(message), error_number(num) {}

const char* FilterException::what() const noexcept
{
    return error_message.c_str();
}

FilterException::~FilterException() noexcept
{
}

int FilterException::getErrorNumber() const noexcept
{
    return error_number;
}
```

So, my question, should I just leave it like this, or make a change in constructor and get rid of `what()` ?

Comment: *"I'm currently working on my own exception class that inherits from std::exception"* - Your constructor definition doesn't look like it.

Comment: And there is no `std::exception` constructor taking a string argument, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/exception

Comment: Perhaps [a `std::exception` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception) could help? Especially about [the constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/exception).

Comment: @Ron That is not really true in general and is completely wrong in this particular case since `std::exception` is not a template and is meant to serve as a base class for other exceptions.

Comment: @Ron Presence or absence of virtual destructor has nothing to do with it. The only restriction applied by absence of virtual destructor is inability to keep ownership of derived class instance through a pointer to a base class.

Comment: @Ron [`std::exception`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception) is *not* a container and *has* a [virtual destructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/~exception).  It was designed with inheritance in mind and the standard library already has an entire hierarchy of exception classes based on it.

Comment: Use `std::runtime_error` as your base class (as it already takes a const char * / std::string argument). See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error

Comment: @VTT My bad. Learned something new today.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, the `std::exception("message")` constructor is an implementation detail for VC++. It is not present in most other implementations.

Storing the what-message in a `std::string` seems handy at first, but it adds a corner case for low memory situations: Copying the string *might* result in a `bad_alloc` exception. And having a new exception happen while trying to handle the first one is not that good.

One option to deriving directly from [`std::exception`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/exception) is to instead derive from one of the predefined exceptions in [`<stdexcept>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception), for example [`std::runtime_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error). These exceptions *do* have constructors taking string parameters and have already somehow solved the double-exception problem. Probably by *not* storing a `std::string`.

Comment: [except.throw/7](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/except#throw-7) may be referenced for an evidence that re-throwing is bad.

Comment: @xskxzr - Yes, I didn't want to go into details on exactly *how* bad it is. Or that it might differ if a `bad_alloc` happens while constructing the exception object or while actually throwing it. I would just try to avoid this!