# Why are C++ exceptions (potentially) copied

Tags: c++, exception, copy-constructor

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48127760/4994337) and pages like [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/exception), I learned that exceptions might be copied in the process of being thrown.  I also learned that this copying must not throw any additional exceptions, otherwise `std::terminate()` is called.  This makes it difficult to write exception classes, since e.g. a `std::string` could throw an exception when it's copied.

My question: Why does C++ allow the compiler to copy exceptions?  What would be the disadvantage of throwing them by reference or pointer, and requiring programmers to catch them by reference or pointer, not by value?

It seems like a solution could be to wrap any non-trivial members in something like a `std::shared_ptr` and copy that pointer instead of the object it holds.  But then we lose all the potential advantages of copying (e.g. the fact that you can edit the copy while the original stays unchanged).  So why does C++ insist on being able to copy the exception at all?

Comment: the answer you link makes no mention of copying the exception. It talks about copying the `std::string` when constructing the exception

Comment: in general you cannot forbid someone to copy an exception you throw. Your quesiton basically asks why the standard is how it is, which imho is too broad / opinion based

Comment: btw out-of-memory is something you rarely can recover from. If you are not working on something super-critical I would not worry too much about creating an exception throwing a second one

Comment: Are you aware of [`std::current_exception`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/current_exception)? If not, inspecting what it does, and thinking about what must happen, should answer your question.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 What I meant was: if the standard would forbid the compiler to copy exceptions during exception handling, you wouldn't HAVE to provide a copy constructor. You can forbid someone to copy any object by not providing a copy constructor. It could work the same way for exceptions (i.e. you can only catch them by value if they have a copy constructor). Since I don't see a need to copy exceptions during handling (maybe I'm missing something), I was wondering why the standard allows it, given the trouble it causes. You're right about out-of-memory; I just realized that too.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik No I wasn't, but I don't understand how this answers my question...

Comment: Try to think about what must happen in order for `exception_ptr` to work when the exception object gets constructed in automatic scope, for the duration of the `catch` block, as is the typical implementation. Read what `current_exception` and `exception_ptr` does.

Comment: @PieterNuyts Generally speaking, indeed, all books suggest avoiding `catch` by *copy*. Precisely because copy-constructor can throw during error-handling and resulting into `std::terminate`. (Un)fortunately, *C++* let us widely playing with the syntax (e.g., protected virtual destructor, with multiple protected inheritances, etc... just WTF). However, as in many cases of the language, the answer I often hear is: "it could happen to solve a particular design with that peculiar syntax". In this particular case, I guess the advantage of the copy is the same as passing by copy in a function

Comment: you can throw eg an `int`, having extra rules for not allowing exceptions being copyable would make the standard even more complex. I am not saying that what you say makes no sense, I just think it is hard/impossible to answer your question, other than "thats how it is defined in the standard". Note that different c++ gurus are working on exceptions on a fundamental level and we can stay tuned for what comes next.

Comment: @BiagioFesta - catching by copy or by reference is not material, here. Even if you catch a reference, `current_exception` will then be required to copy the current exception object, in order to construct its `exception_ptr`, because exception objects get typically constructed in automatic scope. Having an exception object always getting constructed in dynamic scope eliminates the need for exceptions to be copyable, but adds a bunch of overhead that's not needed 99% of the time. So, construct in auto scope, and copy the exception object only when it's absolutely required.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik how is `current_exception` related to my comment? My question's interpretation essentially is: *"why does c++ standard allow catching by copy? (since it's potentially dangerous)"*. Agree, `current_exception` *may* require a copy of thrown exception, but it seems to be off-topic here since that function is completely safe even in case of throw on copy. What is your point here?

Comment: @BiagioFesta - the point is that `this_exception` ***may*** require a copy to be made, as you acknowledged. Full stop. This means that exception objects ***must*** be copyable, else `terminate`. Simple logic. End of story. Nothing more needs to be extrapolated.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Clearly, the logic is not so simple. The OP's question is about *"why does C++ standard allow catching by copy"*. The fact that `current_exception` may or not require a copy of the thrown object does not imply anything (logic implication), at least is not the implication of why we need catch by copy. Indeed, `current_exception` is a feature introduced in the C++11 standard, while catching an object by copying is something we have even before.

Comment: @BiagioFesta but the issue is not catching by copy but throwing by copy. And all C++ implementations actually make copies during throw to ensure that life-time of exception object is firmly under control of implementation (and so can even outlive current thread when needed), while making copies during catch is private business of catcher. In fact lot of coding standards suggest catching by reference to const since standard exceptions are polymorphic and so potential copy of base class subobject is slicing the exception.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments to my question, I think this more or less answers it (though my wording may be inaccurate here and there):

**Why copying exceptions is allowed**

Most exceptions are thrown by value, i.e.

```cpp
throw my_exception("This is wrong!);
```

as opposed to throwing a pointer like

```cpp
throw new my_exception("This is wrong!);
```

When an exception is thrown by value, it is allocated on the stack, and since the stack will be unwound, it *has* to be copied in order to propagate it up the stack.

So if the standard would not require exceptions to be copyable, it would have to require that all exceptions be thrown as pointers to heap-allocated objects.  But as Sam Varshavchik pointed out, this adds some overhead that is usually not needed.  Exceptions are typically small objects, so copying them can be expected to cause less overhead than allocating and deallocating them on the heap.

**The problem is not as big as it seems**

As formerlyknownas_463035818 pointed out, getting an out-of-memory exception (`bad_alloc`) while copying another exception is not something most programmers should worry about.  If memory is so full that there's no space for a copy of the exception, the program was almost certainly going to crash soon anyway.

However, it is important to write exceptions in such a way that their copy constructors don't throw all kinds of other exceptions, since that would terminate the program, while it may have been able to catch the original exception and recover from it.